# Swift 5 test build fails with missing Provisioning Profile error

Tags: swift, provisioning-profile

I am trying to build my iOS app from the command line using this command :

```
 $ CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO xcodebuild -target 'MyApp' -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release
```

But it fails with the following error :

```
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: "MyApp" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyProject')
```

Im not interested in signing my app at all. I just want to be able to build from the command line.

Is anyone aware what I am doing wrong?
BTW, I have NOT downloaded any provisioning profile from Apple but Xcode is able to build and run the app. Why is that?